# Run process with non-root user in docker container

Tags: docker, permissions, uid

I'm building redis sentinal image that `run.sh` should run as non-rootuser

`run.sh`

```
  while true; do
    master=$(redis-cli -h ${REDIS_SENTINEL_SERVICE_HOST} -p ${REDIS_SENTINEL_SERVICE_PORT} --csv SENTINEL get-master-addr-by-name mymaster | tr ',' ' ' | cut -d' ' -f1)
    if [[ -n ${master} ]]; then
      master="${master//\"}"
    else
      master=$(hostname -i)
    fi

    redis-cli -h ${master} INFO
    if [[ "$?" == "0" ]]; then
      break
    fi
    echo "Connecting to master failed.  Waiting..."
    sleep 10
  done

  sentinel_conf=/home/ubuntu/sentinel.conf

  echo "sentinel monitor mymaster ${master} 6379 2" > ${sentinel_conf}
  echo "sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 60000" >> ${sentinel_conf}
  echo "sentinel failover-timeout mymaster 180000" >> ${sentinel_conf}
  echo "sentinel parallel-syncs mymaster 1" >> ${sentinel_conf}
  echo "bind 0.0.0.0" >> ${sentinel_conf}

  redis-sentinel ${sentinel_conf} --protected-mode no
}

function launchslave() {
  while true; do
    master=$(redis-cli -h ${REDIS_SENTINEL_SERVICE_HOST} -p ${REDIS_SENTINEL_SERVICE_PORT} --csv SENTINEL get-master-addr-by-name mymaster | tr ',' ' ' | cut -d' ' -f1)
    if [[ -n ${master} ]]; then
      master="${master//\"}"
    else
      echo "Failed to find master."
      sleep 60
      exit 1
    fi
    redis-cli -h ${master} INFO
    if [[ "$?" == "0" ]]; then
      break
    fi
    echo "Connecting to master failed.  Waiting..."
    sleep 10
  done
  sed -i "s/%master-ip%/${master}/" /redis-slave/redis.conf
  sed -i "s/%master-port%/6379/" /redis-slave/redis.conf
  redis-server /redis-slave/redis.conf --protected-mode no
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine:3.4

RUN apk add --no-cache redis sed bash busybox-suid
#su: must be suid to work properly
COPY redis-master.conf /redis-master/redis.conf
COPY redis-slave.conf /redis-slave/redis.conf
RUN adduser -D ubuntu
USER ubuntu
COPY run.sh /home/ubuntu/run.sh
CMD [ "sh", "/home/ubuntu/run.sh" ]
ENTRYPOINT [ "bash", "-c" ]
```

I deployed in Openshift. The container is continuously restarting and I dont see any logs also. I have seen the some logs before when the "run.sh" is root(default) i.e not mentioned any `adduser` in `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact):

> ```
> Both CMD and ENTRYPOINT instructions define what command gets executed when running a container.
> There are few rules that describe their co-operation:
> 1. Dockerfile should specify at least one of CMD or ENTRYPOINT commands.
> 2. CMD will be overridden when running the container with alternative arguments.
> ```

`CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` layers are completely different in the above `Dockerfile`, so `ENTRYPOINT` overrides `CMD` layer and that's why `CMD` layer is never executed.

Just delete `ENTRYPOINT` layer from the `Dockerfile`, it is not needed here:

```
FROM alpine:3.4

RUN apk add --no-cache redis sed bash busybox-suid
#su: must be suid to work properly
COPY redis-master.conf /redis-master/redis.conf
COPY redis-slave.conf /redis-slave/redis.conf
RUN adduser -D ubuntu
USER ubuntu
COPY run.sh /home/ubuntu/run.sh
CMD [ "sh", "/home/ubuntu/run.sh" ]
```

**Update:**

I see that `[[ ]]` is used in `run.sh` script. This construction works in `bash`, not in `sh`. That's why the `Dockerfile` should be the following:

```
FROM alpine:3.4

RUN apk add --no-cache redis sed bash busybox-suid
#su: must be suid to work properly
COPY redis-master.conf /redis-master/redis.conf
COPY redis-slave.conf /redis-slave/redis.conf
RUN adduser -D ubuntu
USER ubuntu
COPY run.sh /home/ubuntu/run.sh
CMD [ "bash", "/home/ubuntu/run.sh" ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer which makes sense. But still i'm getting permission denied error. Please check Update1 in question.

Comment: @Veerendra added additional info to the answer.

Comment: Thanks again. I have looked into the issue. This is purely related to Openshift. Any way, according to my question, your answer is correct.(That's I'm removing Update1 to avoid confusion for other user)